# Is knowledge innate or is it empirical?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, empiricism

Are we conceived with innate knowledge and understanding of this world? Such as a the structure of language. See Chomsky.

Or do we only understand the world by our experience of it and language and communication is developed by interaction with our environment? Or both?

If man created a conscious AI, would that put a lid on the mystery or would that raise more questions?

Comment: This is essentially the classical debate [rationalism vs. empiricism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationalism-empiricism/). Kant's mid-term between both is the most accepted position: part of knowledge comes from experience, but another part is developed purely by reason for experience to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

To my undestanding, consciousness is an innate thing to us.

Going by definition, since knowledge is a form of awareness and consciousness is   awareness too in a way, we could say that indeed we are conceived with a from of innate knowledge.

Understanding on the other hand, is not just a collection of "knowledge", it is related to the process of abstraction and I can't see how this can be done without experiencing and interracting with the environment; abstraction "needs" data and especially data from the "outside" world.

Comment: Could you say experience draws out the innate knowledge?  As we learn language it is by the recognition of events and the association of sounds to those events. Once a familiarity with a sound to an experience of similar events, those sounds can be used to communicate with one another? Once we establish communication we can get a sense of consciousness?

Comment: Heraclitus vs Parmenides! (again)

Comment: Nothing does change take for instance if the proposition that energy|mass is conserved, although changes happen perhaps in the distribution overall there is no change it cycles but there is no overall change if that proposition is true, mass/energy = 1? Well that's my take on you last comment?

Comment: Sorry I have little knowledge of the history of philosophy, I have to research comments etc, all my reasoning comes from no formal education in philosophy.

Comment: I will also add were Heraclitus and Parmenides phillosophers that were viewed with notable contempt by other phillospohers of the day?

Comment: Heraclitus and Parmenides set the stage of Philosophy; they are the root.

Comment: OK, I can get a bit paranoid I thought you were criticising me.

Comment: not at all, wiki: Parmenides has been considered the founder of ontology and has, through his influence on Plato, influenced the whole history of Western philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

One starting point to consider in this connection: is the concept of the *a priori*/*a posteriori* distinction itself *a priori* or *a posteriori*? If the latter, then something of pure rationalism seems perhaps undermined (if the very notion of non-empirical knowledge is yet empirical, whence its significance?). Or if the distinction is rationalistic, then this might testify against empiricism to some extent.

The more philosophically mature point of view then comes from asking if the bare concept of knowledge is only one or the other (only empiricistic or only rationalistic), and realizing that it seems ambiguous, as a question, between these, and other, states. So if [observation is theory-laden](https://web.cortland.edu/russellk/courses/300sci/hdouts/laden.htm), then knowledge from observation won't be exclusively *a priori* or *a posteriori*, but will involve an interface between these kinds of states.

You can interpret the situation functionalistically, then: a true *tabula rasa* would have mere identity for its consciousness-function, taking empirical inputs and spitting out the same as outputs *f*(E) = E, for whichever E. But so long as our consciousness has some further structure encoded into it, E will, or at least can, be modulated on input, yielding perhaps E + X, say, for some *a priori* calibration X.

Comment: I am always amazed by the complexity of your mind!

Comment: @IoannisPaizis thank you. OTOH it does take me too much to get to a point, betimes... I wonder whether I could have left this answer of mine at, "Observation is theory-laden," and have been done with it?

Comment: @IoannisPaizis hear hear! I used to think I had a broad vocabulary until I met Kristian!

Comment: @Marco Ocram, I am heading for ... Zen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have (fallible) access to an external world that does exist outside of our minds, then I'd say it's actually both -- they are not mutually exclusive propositions.

Studies of human and animal behavior and brain structure show that there are very specialized structures in all brains, and that each species has what we call instincts. Instincts are nothing but innate knowledge, hard won from the deaths of countless (non)-ancestors who unfortunately didn't have the benefit of these instincts, or to newborn reptiles and fish

Examples include our (and many animals) sense of object permanence. This is hilariously shown in many [funny pet videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVllknjxnfs) and more professionally [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/PBR.16.1.150).

One could argue that this is still just learned "on the job". In that case, I'd point to newborn mammals who have instinct to find milk and an number of specialized reflexes and instincts to protect them. Our minds appear to come with a basic intuition of physics and planar geometry and other knowledge.